# ADODB Excel SQL statement to write to next available row

Tags: sql, excel, vbscript, adodb

I am currently able to read and update data in my Excel spreadsheet from using an ADODB connection in my VBScript. That is working smoothly and I understand how to manipulate different columns and different rows with whatever I want.

My issue is, I now have a need for a new row of data to be entered. How does it know where to place it? The code I have been using always give some sort of reference point: example:

```
rs.Open "Update [links$] Set [F" & arrLocals(i) & "]= '" & arrChangeData(i) & "' Where [F2] = '" & arrFormID(j) & "'", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

so according to that, it pretty much means *do stuff to this row as long as you are working on the row with `arrFormID(j)` matching column `F2`.* But, if you want a new row, I don't know what there is to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an [`insert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx) statement. SQL statements like `insert`, `delete`, and `update` typically aren't treated as "row-returning" statements, so it usually makes more sense to use the `Connection` object itself to perform the operation rather than a `Recordset`. For example:

```vb
Dim cn
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "<your Excel connection string>"

cn.Execute "update [links$] set ... where ..."
cn.Execute "insert into [links$] values (...)"
cn.Execute "delete from [links$] where ..."

cn.Close
```

The most basic `insert` statement just provides values for each column in your table/worksheet, in the same sequence the columns appear:

```vb
cn.Execute "insert into [links$] values ('col1value','col2value','col3value')"
```

Comment: Thanks Bond, so are you saying `cn.Execute "insert into [links$] values (...)"` will put the values into the next available row?

Comment: It "inserts" a new row. For Excel, it should be added to the bottom. For a traditional database, there isn't really a sense of "bottom".

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to use the RecordSet interface, for example:

```vb
Option Explicit

Const adCmdTable = 2
Const adLockBatchOptimistic = 4
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

dim ado, rs
set ado = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

ado.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=example.xlsx;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
ado.Open
'ado.Execute "DROP TABLE Sheet1"
ado.Execute "CREATE TABLE Sheet1 (ID int, name VARCHAR)"
rs.Open "Sheet1", ado, , adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable 


dim i
for i = 0 to 4
    ' create a new record, populate the fields then update the data source
    rs.AddNew
    rs.Fields("ID").Value = i
    rs.Fields("name").Value = "Dave"
    rs.Update
next 'i

' also showing populating a dictionary to pass to update() instead
' of inserting into the record's fields directly
rs.AddNew

dim dict
set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict("ID") = 99
dict("name") = "Geoff"

rs.Update dict.Keys(), dict.Items()

rs.Close
ado.Close
```

Gives you

```
ID | name
----------  
 0 | Dave  
 1 | Dave  
 2 | Dave  
 3 | Dave  
 4 | Dave  
99 | Geoff
```